# Proving $ x \in (A \cap B) - C \;\to\; x \notin A \bigtriangleup B \bigtriangleup C $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How to prove this?
$$ x \in ((A \cap B) - C) \;\to\; x \notin ((A \bigtriangleup B) \bigtriangleup C)$$

Comment: What is the difficulty? $x\in(A\cap B)\setminus C$ iff $x$ belongs to $A,B$ but not $C$. Whilst $x\in A\Delta B\Delta C$ iff $x$ belongs to an odd number of $A,B,C$.

Comment: @almagest but I thought it should be some kind of sequence like ⋃n=0∞(An+1∩Acn)=⋃n=0∞{n+1}={1,2,3,⋯}=N∖{0}.... Like I mean prove it mathematicaly

Comment: it's simply because $((A\cap B)-C)\cap ((A\bigtriangleup B)\bigtriangleup C)=\varnothing$

Comment: If $x\in(A\cap B)-C\land x\in ((A\bigtriangleup B)\bigtriangleup C)$ implies $((A\cap B)-C)\cap ((A\bigtriangleup B)\bigtriangleup C)\neq\varnothing$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove this by contradiction, if $x∈(A∩B)−C∧x∈((A△B)△C)$ we have:
$$ ((A∩B)−C)∩((A△B)△C)≠\varnothing\tag{$\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$}$$
Hence proved $x∈(A∩B)−C→x∉A△B△C\tag*{$\square$}$

---

If it's not obvious that $((A∩B)−C)∩((A△B)△C)=\varnothing$,
Here is a detailed proof with Set Identities:

\begin{align}
&\hspace{3ex}((A\cap B)-C)\cap ((A\bigtriangleup B)\bigtriangleup C)\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^c)\cap ((A\bigtriangleup B)\bigtriangleup C)\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^c)\cap ((A-B)\cup(B-A))\bigtriangleup C)\tag*{Symmetric difference}\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^c)\cap \big((((A-B)\cup(B-A))- C)\tag*{Symmetric difference}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup (C-((A-B)\cup(B-A)))\big)\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^c)\cap \big((((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup (C\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))^c)\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap (C^c\cap \big((((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Associative Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup (C\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))^c))\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  \big((C^c\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Distributive Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup (C^c\cap (C\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))^c))\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  \big((C^c\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Associative Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup ((C^c\cap C)\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))^c)\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  \big((C^c\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Complement Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup (\varnothing\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))^c)\big)\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  \big((C^c\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Domination Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup\varnothing\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  (C^c\cap((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Identity Law}\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  (((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c\cap C^c)\tag*{Communative Law}\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap  (((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c))\cap C^c)\tag*{Idempotent Law}\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap  ((A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)))\cap C^c\tag*{Associative Law}\\
&=(((A\cap B)\cap  (A\cap B^c))\tag*{Distributive Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup((A\cap B)\cap(B\cap A^c)))\cap C^c\\
&=(((A\cap B)\cap  (B^c\cap A))\tag*{Communative Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup((B\cap A)\cap(A^c\cap B)))\cap C^c\\
&=(((A\cap ((B\cap B^c)\cap A)))\tag*{Associative Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup((B\cap ((A\cap A^c)\cap B))))\cap C^c\\
&=(((A\cap (\varnothing\cap A)))\tag*{Associative Law}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\cup((B\cap (\varnothing\cap B))))\cap C^c\\
&=(\varnothing\cup\varnothing)\cap C^c\tag*{Domination Law}\\
&=\varnothing\cap C^c\tag*{Idempotent Law}\\
&=\varnothing\tag*{Domination Law}\\
\end{align}

Comment: The second part is quite long: if $x\in(A∩B)−C)$ and $x\in(A△B)△C$, then $x\in A\cap B$. This implies that $x\notin A△B$. So $x\in C$. This contradicts $x\in(A∩B)−C)$ so $((A∩B)−C)∩((A△B)△C)=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Taladris thats exactly right

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to note $A\triangle B\triangle C$ comprises those elements of an odd number of $A,\,B,\,C$ (more generally $\triangle_{i=1}^nA_i$ has this property for $n\ge1$, by an easy proof by induction), but each element of $(A\cap B)\setminus C$ is an element of precisely two of them, namely $A,\,B$.